# Casting an object with events defined to an interface type causes an internal compiler error

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-runtime

I've got an interface with a simple signature:

```
namespace Serial {

public interface struct ISerial
{
    uint16_t func1();
    uint16_t func2();
};
}
```

and then a class type which implements the interface

```
namespace Serial {
    public delegate void MyEventClass();

public ref class MySerial sealed : public ISerial {
public:
    event MyEventClass MyEvent;

    MySerial();

    ...
};
}
```

but elsewhere, as a default parameter to a function, I try to store a reference to a type MySerial as an ISerial ^

```
void
begin(
    Serial::ISerial ^s = ref new Serial::MySerial
);
```

causes: `error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.`

when I remove the event from the class definition, everything compiles fine. I'm finding little information on this error.

Comment: Are you sure this is C++ and not some Microsoft language?

Comment: It is the component extensions to Visual C++ (often abbreviated as C++/CX).

Answer (score 0):

I verified this on VS 2013 and it works with a few minor changes (all generated based on normal compiler errors, not an ICE). I don't have VS 2015 available right now, but will log a bug if it still repros.

First the struct (should be unchanged)

```
namespace Serial 
{
  public interface struct ISerial
  {
    uint16_t func1();
    uint16_t func2();
  };
}
```

Then the class (couple of changes noted below):

```
namespace Serial 
{
  public delegate void MyEventClass();

  public ref class MySerial sealed : public ISerial{
  public:
    event MyEventClass^ MyEvent;
    MySerial(){}
    virtual uint16_t func1() { return 42; }
    virtual uint16_t func2() { return 42; }
  };
}
```

And the usage:

```
void foo()
{
  using namespace Serial;

  ISerial^ foo = ref new MySerial();
}
```

Basically you need to add the hat (`^`) to the event type, and you need to add `virtual` to the methods (but do not add `override`).

[See more here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/737cydt1(v=vs.110).aspx)